# Form table based on previous inputs

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I'm new to working with PHP and have a problem I can't seem to find the answer to.

I have to create an event creation form spread across multiple pages.  On one page there is to be a table that vertically will have ticket types listing only ones selected on a previous page and horozontally there is a 'sections' column based also on a previous page.  The table will then allow the user to enter a price to then be assigned to the ticket type depending on the different sections.

My question being, is it possible to do this with html/PHP alone?  I am using the POST method to move between the pages of the form and then adding it all to the database at the end but should I do it a different way to achieve this?

I hope the question makes sense but I'm coming from a non lingo position.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to take:

1. Use the POST method as you described.
2. Use session variables to store data across pages.
3. Use jQuery/javascript to hide/show different forms on one page (takes out the need to multi POST or store data in session).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do (not necessarily *should*, that's your own judgment call) is save all the `POST`ed data as session variables. This can help you clean up code clutter, as otherwise you'll have to `POST` all the data from all the forms to all the forms in order to maintain the information through all page navigations.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the first page has a form method with POST this could be done. 
Here are the steps:

1. On the first page, the user will submit the data by the POST method.
2. On the second page, save the data in a temporary variable as such : $temp_var = $_POST['data'];
3. Create the second page with data based on first.
4. (On submit) Save the new data with old data into database

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for [sessions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)!

On your first page, your form can submit with POST and then you can store the data in the user's session:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['form_submission'] = $_POST;
```

Then, on page #2 (or any other page), you can access it with:

```
session_start();
$form_variable = $_SESSION['form_submission']['field_name'];
```

You can more-generally store/retrieve them to make it more readable as well:

```
$_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST['field1'];
$field1 = $_SESSION['field1'];
```

Comment: I'm hitting a wall.  I am adding the session start code at the start of each page but on the second page I'm trying to add some posted info to a var using $venueName = $_POST['venue_name']; within the <?php session_start(); section.  On this page I am then able to <?php echo $venueName; ?> but on the next page I can't.

Comment: This is expected behavior. You will need to re-declare variables on any/every page you want to use them on. So, if you want `$venueName` on page #2, you declare it on page #2. If you want it on page #3 too, you also must declare it on page #3.

Comment: at the moment I have it as $_SESSION['venue_name'] = $_POST['venue_name'];   $venueName = $_SESSION['venue_name'];   as without using $_POST it doesn't work.  Where is the advantage over just saying $venueName = $_POST['venue_name'];  ?

Comment: @user1546076 The advantage can be seen when you need to access the value on a different page. `$venueName = $_POST['venue_name'];` will work absolutely fine, if and only if a form is being POSTed on the current page. If you want to access the value on a different page that's not currently being POSTed to, having the value stored in the session is a great benefit.

Comment: This is the point that is confusing me I think.  As I have a form that is split over a number of pages I need the info to move along it so it can be all dealt with at the end.  But to do this do I have to set it every page along the form using $_SESSION the same way you do when using $_POST?

Comment: On page #1, you have a form. When the form is submitted, process & store the submission into `$_SESSION`. Then, on page #2, you can use the values in `$_SESSION` however you want; also, say you have another form on page #2. When the user submits this one, you can process & add this submission into `$_SESSION` as well. At this point, you have submission values from 2 different forms in the user's session and you can use them however you want. On page #1, you can use `$_POST` to process page #1's form. On page #2, you can use `$_POST` for page #2's form, and `$_SESSION` for page #1's, etc.

Comment: That is what I thought but for some reason it isn't working for me.  on the later pages I am using $_SESSION['name']; to call the data but I'm getting no return.

Answer (score 0):

PHP and HTML will be fine to manage the kind of system you have in mind.

To get you started:

PHP uses sessions to manage data from one page to the next creating a process like this:

1. User fills in first form
2. POST request to web server with data
3. PHP script interprets data and creates a new view on the page or redirects to another page.

in your PHP scripts at the top of EVERY page you use:

```
session_start();
```

You can now save data to the session:

```
$_SESSION['mySessionVar'] = 'This is my session variable';
```

Whenever you need to retrieve from a session, make sure that a) `session_start()` has been called and b) retrieve it like this:

```
$myVariable = $_SESSION['mySessionVar'];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand it to a point but unsure exactly how I should add it to each page.  At this point I have each entry stored using:

Comment: as you're new to PHP try just adding it at the top of every page where you open your first PHP tags: `<?php session_start(); ...`

Comment: That way you can use $_SESSION at any position in the page.

Comment: I'm hitting a wall. I am adding the session start code at the start of each page but on the second page I'm trying to add some posted info to a var using $venueName = $_POST['venue_name']; within the <?php session_start(); section. On this page I am then able to <?php echo $venueName; ?> but on the next page I can't.

Comment: So are you making sure you save your var to the session in the first instance? `$_SESSION['venueName'] = $venueNAme` and then when you need it again: `$venueName = $_SESSION['venueName'];`

Comment: why would I need to declare it twice or do you mean I will need to declare it for each page?